# Searching table with Pagination - only first page is searched

Tags: angular

I'm Learning Angular and building an app to do so.  I've got a page that displays a list of clients from a database.  The page itself uses Pagination to organize the tables data.  I'm able to search the table for data based on the filters setup to search the following columns: organizationName, username and lastName.

The issue I'm running into is I'm only getting results back from the table page thats currently being viewed.  It looks as though the remaining pages are not being searched - (as they aren't returning any results).

The search is being conducted using a pipe to filter through everything.  Any ideas on what I'm not doing correct here?

**clients-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Clients } from '../../../../_models/clients';
import { Pagination, PaginatedResult } from '../../../../_models/pagination';
import { ClientsService } from '../../../../_services/clients.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients-table',
  templateUrl: './clients-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients-table.component.scss']
})
export class ClientsTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() clients: Clients[];
  @Input() pagination: Pagination;
  public searchText: string;
  public customerData: any;

  constructor(private clientsService: ClientsService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.clients = data['clients'].result;
      this.pagination = data['clients'].pagination;
    });
  }

  pageChanged(event: any): void {
    this.pagination.currentPage = event.page;
    this.loadClients();
  }

  loadClients() {
    this.clientsService.getClients(this.pagination.currentPage, this.pagination.itemsPerPage)
      .subscribe((res: PaginatedResult<Clients[]>) => {
      this.clients = res.result;
      this.pagination = res.pagination;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

**clients-table.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Client List
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search by name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            class="clickable"
            *ngFor="let client of clients | grdFilter: {organizationName: searchText, username:searchText,  lastName: searchText}; let i=index;"
            [routerLink]="['/manage/clients/', client.id]"
          >
            <td class="clickable">{{ client.organizationName }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.country }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.firstName + " " + client.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.phoneNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.validTo }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <pagination class="text-center"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        [totalItems]="pagination.totalItems"
        [itemsPerPage]="pagination.itemsPerPage"
        [(ngModel)]="pagination.currentPage"
        (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
        previousText="&lsaquo;"
        nextText="&rsaquo;"
        firstText="&laquo;"
        lastText="&raquo;">
      </pagination>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**grd-filter-pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'grdFilter'
})
export class GrdFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
        if (!filter) {
            return items;
        }

        if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
            return items;
        }

        if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
            const filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

            if (defaultFilter) {
                return items.filter(item =>
                    filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                        (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === '', true));
            } else {
                return items.filter(item => {
                    return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
                        return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] === '';
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Your loadClients() method only loads clients from the current page.
Here you have two options: Have a method that submits the search term to an endpoint that returns the result filtered, or a method that get all clients from database and filter on the front end (not recommended).